# MySQL IN Clause with specific and general records

Tags: mysql

I have this query, which does what I need:

```
select *
from Clients.numclients_devices a
where 

a.Device in( 'device A','device B','device C','device D')

and a.Reference in ( 'reference a', 'reference d','reference e', 'reference x', 'reference y', 'reference l', 'reference m', 'reference n', 'reference o' )

and a.date ='2017-05-01'
```

My question is if there is a better way?

I have 4 devices which one of them as different references, for device a and device b I want a specific references, but for the other 2 i want all existent references...

The device A I want the reference 'a' and 'd', and for the device B i want the reference 'e' (they have more references), but the rest are the only references for the other devices.

so how can I restrict the references for device A and B, and say i want all for the other devices?

Comment: I'm confused.  If the logic does what you want, why do you want to change it?  The logic doesn't seem to implement the logic that you express (which is rather confusing, but clearly more complicated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple `OR`s:

```
select *
from Clients.numclients_devices a
where (
  a.Device = 'device A' and a.Reference in ('reference a', 'reference d')
  or
  a.Device = 'device B' and a.Reference = 'reference e'
  or
  a.Device in ('device C','device D')
)
and a.date ='2017-05-01'
```

Comment: (sorry for the delay, i was in vacations). Thank you so much for your reply, still in the begging on sql, so sometimes I dont remember something simple.

Comment: I didnt wanted to write all the references for the devices "c" and "d", but i guess with "or" i can just put or a.device  in ('device C', 'device D'). without the "and".

Comment: Yeah, you're right, that "and" wasn't needed. I'll edit the answer.